# Changing location of "About me" section

Tags: plugins, menus

I am using the [Twenty Twelve theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwelve/) and am happy with the appearance of my site.

However, I would like my picture and about section to appear on the top right of my site without visitors having to click *About* on the main menu.

I would also like my picture and the about section to be at the sidebar widget area just above or below my "connect" plugin icons and above the search bar section on my front page. My front page is not static, but changes to show my last post.

My site is [Voraciously Yours](http://voraciouslyyours.com).

Answer (score 1):

In your [child theme's](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) `functions.php`, add the following:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'display-page', 'wpse_239714_page_content' );

function wpse_239714_page_content( $content ) {
    $thispage = get_post( $content['id'] );
    return do_shortcode( $thispage -> post_content );
}
```

This will allow you to display the content of any post or page in a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode), like so:

```
[display-page id="PAGE_ID"]
```

Where `PAGE_ID` is the numeric ID of your *About* page. See this article on [how to find the correct page ID](https://www.competethemes.com/blog/find-page-id/).

Once you get the page ID (example: `7`), just paste that shortcode in your sidebar *Text widget*:

[image]

Now your content from the *About* page will be shown. From my testing, the image did not show up in the sidebar. However, that can easily be rectified by simply adding the HTML `<img>` tag with a link to your profile picture:

```
<img src="http://i1.wp.com/voraciouslyyours.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/me.jpg?resize=624%2C936" alt="About Sheena" />
```